# Web request with input type fields

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, zoho

Trying to make an api call here is code

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://creator.zoho.eu/api/programerAnel/xml/testAPP/form/Edit/record/update");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
        string postData = @"
        < input type=""hidden"" name =""authtoken"" value=""12333"">
        < input type = ""hidden"" name = ""scope"" id = ""scope"" value = ""creatorapi"">
        < input type = ""text"" name = ""criteria"" value = ""UpdateUj=123"" >
        < input type = ""text"" name = ""Kljuc"" value = ""1"" >
        < input type = ""submit"" value = ""Update Record"" > ";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.  
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.  
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.  
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.  
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.  
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.  
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.  
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.  
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

But it keep throwing me response .

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.'

Is it possible to send postData in format like this at all ?

The requests are sent to [Zoho - REST API](https://www.zoho.eu/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-edit-records.html)

Comment: that POST body is not `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Do a quick search for how to format correctly.

Comment: @Crowcoder What do you mean by correct form. On url provided under the text they request format like this

Comment: It looks to me like they are showing an example html form that would post to their api, not the raw http request details. But, I could be wrong. If I am it is a bizarre way to design an API.

Comment: @Crowcoder this is what they said . Zoho can make only simple GET and Simple POST request. (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: form url encoding looks like this: `authtoken=12333&scope=creatorapi&criteria=UpdateUj=123 ... etc` . Though you will have to encode the data especially since the data itself has `=` character.

Comment: @Crowcoder  Is it up to me or making this request is way complicated ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159335/discussion-between-programer-anel-and-crowcoder).

Answer (score 3):

I don't yet know what other problems you may have, but start by properly formatting your post body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. What you are sending is HTML and I don't believe that is the intent of their documentation. They are showing you how to build an HTML form as opposed to how to hit the API from code. If you had a form like that on a web page it would post this to the API:

```
authtoken=12333&scope=creatorapi&criteria=UpdateUj%3d123&Kljuc=1
```

Notice I encoded the `=` character with `%3d`. You should `UrlEncode` all your data to be safe.